# Detect in a program if a point is close to a country outline

Tags: borders

I have some data for country borders.
I am making a small program that need to load a border on demand when a position in the program gets close to a country (which consists of multiple loops of GPS points).

It does not have to be super accurate, but on the other hand, loading a long country like Italy should not be as simple as a single GPS with a distance check. But maybe 4 points would be ok.

I need to keep a small database I reckon of each country with some precomputed params that determine when to load it, so its not CPU intensive. How do I automate generation of such params, I am a bit out of ideas..

Comment: What have you tried? What language/software are you using? If you are using python, I'd recommend looking into [shapely.snap](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). Maybe provide some images of what you are trying to do.

Comment: While Italy isn't a large country, it is highly irregular, so four vertices seems inadequate by four to six orders of magnitude.

Comment: I ended up just drawing a box around each country and check how many degrees I was away from them. Thanks for the replies. I programmed it in Nasal, but shapely seems cool.